# How to improve Nginx, Rails, Passenger memory usage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory, nginx, passenger, sidekiq

I currently have a rails app set up on a Digital Ocean VPS (1GB RAM) trough Cloud 66. The problem being that the VPS' memory runs full with Passenger processes.

The output of `passenger-status`:

```
# passenger-status
Version : 4.0.45
Date    : 2014-09-23 09:04:37 +0000
Instance: 1762
----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 2
Processes     : 2
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/var/deploy/cityspotters/web_head/current#default:
  App root: /var/deploy/cityspotters/web_head/current
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 7675    Sessions: 0       Processed: 599     Uptime: 39m 35s
    CPU: 1%      Memory  : 151M    Last used: 1m 10s ago
  * PID: 7686    Sessions: 0       Processed: 477     Uptime: 39m 34s
    CPU: 1%      Memory  : 115M    Last used: 10s ago
```

The max_pool_size seems to be configured correctly.

The output of `passenger-memory-stats`:

```
# passenger-memory-stats
Version: 4.0.45
Date   : 2014-09-23 09:10:41 +0000
------------- Apache processes -------------
*** WARNING: The Apache executable cannot be found.
Please set the APXS2 environment variable to your 'apxs2' executable's filename, or set the HTTPD environment variable to your 'httpd' or 'apache2' executable's filename.


--------- Nginx processes ---------
PID   PPID  VMSize   Private  Name
-----------------------------------
1762  1     51.8 MB  0.4 MB   nginx: master process /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx
7616  1762  53.0 MB  1.8 MB   nginx: worker process
### Processes: 2
### Total private dirty RSS: 2.22 MB


----- Passenger processes -----
PID   VMSize    Private   Name
-------------------------------
7597  218.3 MB  0.3 MB    PassengerWatchdog
7600  565.7 MB  1.1 MB    PassengerHelperAgent
7606  230.8 MB  1.0 MB    PassengerLoggingAgent
7675  652.0 MB  151.7 MB  Passenger RackApp: /var/deploy/cityspotters/web_head/current
7686  652.1 MB  116.7 MB  Passenger RackApp: /var/deploy/cityspotters/web_head/current
### Processes: 5
### Total private dirty RSS: 270.82 MB
```

.. 2 Passenger RackApp processes, OK.

But when I use the `htop` command, the output is as follows:

[image: htop output]

There seem to be a lot of Passenger Rackup processes. We're also running Sidekiq with the default configuration.

New Relic Server reports the following memory usage:

[image: New Relic server monitoring output]

I tried tuning Passenger settings, adding a load balancer and another server but honestly don't know what to do from here. How can I find out what's causing so much memory usage?

Update: I had to restart ngnix because of some changes and it seemed to free quite a lot of memory.

Comment: Nginx is designed not to grow in memory footprint during operation. If restarting it freed memory, investigate why that is.

Answer (score 4):

Press Shift-H to hide threads in htop.  Those aren't processes but threads within a process.  The key column is RSS: you have two passenger processes at 209MB and 215MB and one Sidekiq process at 154MB.

Short answer: this is completely normal memory usage for a Rails app.  1GB is simply a little small if you want multiple processes for each.  I'd cut down passenger to one process.

Comment: Agreed. I assume this is a 64 bit machine. Perhaps you can free up some by switching to 32 bit, but honestly, 1G is what you give your developers that are in the doghouse for writing low quality code.

Comment: Thanks, the "shift+h" was what I needed to see that they were in fact threads.

Answer (score 1):

Does your application create child processes? If so, then it's likely that those extra "Passenger RackApp" processes are not actually processes created by Phusion Passenger, but are in fact processes created by your own app. You should double check whether your app spawns child processes and whether you clean up those child processes correctly. Also double check whether any libraries you use, also properly clean up their child processes.

I see that you're using Sidekiq and you've configured **25** Sidekiq processes. Those are also eating a lot of memory. A Sidekiq process eats just as much memory as a Passenger RackApp process, because both of them load your entire application (including Rails) in memory. Try reducing the number of Sidekiq processes.

Comment: Thanks Hongli. I completely removed Sidekiq and it improved things a bit, but not drastically. There are still quite a lot of Passenger RackApp processes spawned: http://cl.ly/Xgie. I'm not consciously spawning child processes and at first sight no gem we use does.
I will investigate some more.

Comment: The removal of Sidekiq proved to be good. Once I add it again I will reduce the number of processes and monitor if that was the culprit.

Comment: 25 threads, not processes. Htop shows threads as a separate line.

Comment: @MikePerham I thought htop hides threads by default. But this might be version specific. richard, could you try pressing 'H' in htop? Maybe that hides threads, if showing threads was on by default.

Comment: @Hongli It appears threads were not hidden by default. Hidden: http://cl.ly/XhmW, not hidden: http://cl.ly/XgvW.
I was under the impression the non-Enterprise version did not utilise threading.